# Extract rows that match a set of values and the id count matches to the length of that set of values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like that

```
id|v
----
ab|1
ab|2
yz|1
yz|2
yz|3
```

If in input I have *(1,2)* or *(2,1)*-> i want extract the id *ab*

If in input I have *(1,2,3)* or *(1,3,2)* or *(2,1,3)* or *(2,3,1)* or *(3,1,2)* or *(3,2,1)* -> I want extract the id *yz*

any other input -> nothing

EDIT: 
the input is derived from another table. It can be in a 1 column table (even in an array is fine). Example:

```
v     or    v   or  ...
-           -
1           3
2           2
            1
```

Thanks

Comment: Assuming each combination of (id,v) is unique, here's something to thing about: `SELECT *, v IN (1,2) x FROM my_table;` Hint: Which rows now HAVE a SUM equal to a COUNT ?

Comment: if in input you have (1,3) , what should it extract ?

Comment: if in input I have (1,3)  -> nothing

Comment: if in input you have (1,2,2,3) , what should it extract ?

Comment: if in input I have (1,2,2,3) -> nothing

Comment: Not clear enough. **(1)** how do you intend to pass the input to the query? **(2)** are v values are always a sequence starting with 1 with no duplicates?

Comment: the numbers are always in serial ?
without duplicates or missing values like ?

Comment: There aren't duplicates or missing values ​​in the input (because it is derived from another table). 
I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the input values as the array you can use the `group_concat` function. Something like this:

```
select t.id from (
select id, group_concat(v separator ',') as v_grouped
from temp 
group by id ) as t
where t.v_grouped = group_concat(input separator ',')
```

Comment: Can you explain better please?

Comment: First you group the rows by the `id` ('ab', 'yz' values) to get the `v` values that should be matched. Then the `group_concat` functions joins the values to the string separated by commas. The result of this query is used in the `from` clause of the main query to filter the data.

Comment: What is input? Thanks

Comment: By 'input' I mean the values (i.e. 1, 2, 3) you want to use to find the id. In your case, the result of the other query. You can add ordering to make sure the concatenated input and `v_grouped`is are the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. SO gives me hard time with multiple **count(*)** in code section, so I replaced it with **count(1)**

---

```
select  *
from    my_table as t
where   (select count(1) from my_table t2 where t2.id = t.id) = (select count(1) from my_input)
;
```

---

2. If all numbers are serial without duplicates or missing values than the input could be a single number that represents the number of rows and there is no actual need for a table with all the values.

---

```
set @number_of_rows := 3;

select  *
from    my_table as t
where   (select count(1) from my_table t2 where t2.id = t.id) = @number_of_rows
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You say you have an existing query giving you values you want to look up in your table. So a result may look like this:

```
value
2
1
```

You are looking for IDs in your table that have exactly these values, no more, no less, no different ones. So you want to match the set of values which you can represent as a string of sorted comma-separated values, i.e. `'1,2'`, `'1,2,3'` etc.

Hence the only task is to build these strings (with `GROUP_CONCAT`) and compare:

```
select id
from mytable
group by id
having group_concat(v order by v) in
(
  select group_concat(value order by value)
  from your_existing_query
);
```

If you want to show the records of the IDs thus found:

```
select *
from mytable
where id in
(
  select id
  from mytable
  group by id
  having group_concat(v order by v) in
  (
    select group_concat(value order by value)
    from your_existing_query
  )
);
```

Comment: Very well. Thanks a lot! ;)